# Where can I find a tutorial for PCB?

Tags: documentation

I'm looking at using this [PCB layout program](http://pcb.gpleda.org/) and looking for a tutorial for it.

After skimming through the manual, and a few attempts at guessing how to use it, I have to say that in combination they are a near ideal example of how *Not* to make a UI easy to use. The GUI seems to borrow it's key combinations from vi (despite not being a text editor) and the manual seems to say more about what things do than how to do things.

The closest I can find is [this section](http://pcb.gpleda.org/pcb-20091103/pcb.html#Drawing-and-Removing) that starts with the todo note:

> [...] do a real-world tutorial example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this part](http://pcb.gpleda.org/pcb-20091103/pcb.html#Getting-Started) of the Manual is some kind of tutorial. It guides you through the basics of the programm and shows you how to use them. For further help and howtos of different programm features, the [help forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcb/forums/forum/251829) from the sourceforge page could help too.

edit.: I found [this](http://computerchristmas.com/?link=how_to&HowToId=83) through the developers links page. I guess this is a tutorial for a special controller design using PCB Editor. Maybe there is something more on [this page](http://geda.seul.org/wiki/geda:links) you can use.

Comment: That first link is to the exact section I was referring to as what I don't need.

Comment: Ok, I didn´t know what you read of it and what not. Anyway, this is a very special piece of software. So, i guess if there is a tutorial at all, it will be really hard to find. But I´ll keep looking.